# How to store data returned form a get request into a variable?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, body-parser

Even when I have a matching entry in the database I get null value in error.

Thank you in advance.

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const con = require("../config/keys");
const Validator = require("validator");
const isEmpty = require("./is-empty");

module.exports = function checkIfExists(data, table) {
  let errors = {};

  router.get(`/tools/${table}`, (req, res) => {
    con.query(
      `SELECT * FROM ${table} WHERE particulars = ${data}`,
      (err, result) => {
        if (err)
          return res
            .status(400)
            .json({ errors: "Failed to connect with database" });

        newData = result;
        newData.particulars = !isEmpty(newData.particulars)
          ? newData.particulars
          : "";

        if (!Validator.isEmpty(newData.particulars)) {
          return (errors.particulars = "Particulars already exists");
        }
      }
    );
  });

  return {
    errors,
    isUnique: isEmpty(errors)
  };
};
```

Expected result: When there is an existing particular in the database I want to get the errors into the errors object.

Comment: Totally depends upon your front end - wherever you are calling your api, validate data using your frontend What are you using for frontend? ... OR you can validate data at the backend before returning by using your result to create new object.

Comment: `let myVar = result;` ???